# pip always tries to use a proxy

Tags: python, macos, pip

Unless I define another proxy on the command line every time I try and run pip I get a failure:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Failed to parse: http://localhost:3128:443
```

I've tried setting `--proxy=""` but I get the same error. So at the moment the only way I can use `pip` is if I'm behind a functioning proxy and then defining `--proxy=PROXYURL` will get `pip` working.

There are no proxy settings in my environment, I can't find any `pip` config files.

I'm running on Mac OS 12.2.

Some additional detail:

```
~ $ env | grep -i proxy # Nothing returned, no proxy env variables set
~ $ ls "/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf"
ls: /Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf: No such file or directory
~ $ ls ".config/pip/pip.conf"
ls: .config/pip/pip.conf: No such file or directory
~ $ ls "Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf"
ls: Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf: No such file or directory
~ $ ls "$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf"
ls: /pip.conf: No such file or directory
~ $ export PIP_CONFIG_FILE=os.devnull
~ $ pip3 install -U auto-sklearn
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Failed to parse: http://localhost:3128:443

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: `export https_proxy=""` and `export http_proxy=""`

Comment: Also investigate config files: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

Comment: @ZWang no proxy environment variables are set

Comment: @phd thanks for the pointer to the docs -- I've confirmed none of the config files exist and settings PIP_CONFIG_FILE to os.devnull does not prevent pip from trying to use a proxy